# Getting Producer_down in Erlang/Brod but no problems in java implementation

Tags: apache-kafka, erlang

Thought i had this fixed but appearently missed something: in Erlang/Brod i am getting a producer down error

```
  {ok, _} = application:ensure_all_started(brod),
  ok = brod:start_client(KafkaBootstrapEnpoint, client1, _client_config = []),

  ok = brod:start_producer(client1, KafkaQ, _ProducerConfig = []),
  {ok, Partition_count} = brod:get_partitions_count(client1, KafkaQ ),
  case catch brod:produce_sync(client1, KafkaQ, KafkaPartition, <<"key1">>, <<"Key2">>) of
      {ok, _} ->
        ok;
      Error ->
        io:format("unexpedted response for partition: ~p error: ~p ~n", [KafkaPartition, Error])
  end,
```

The error message is as follows:

```
> =INFO REPORT==== 31-Mar-2020::07:59:45 ===
client client1 connected to 10.10.1.35:9092
unexpedted response for partition: 1 error: {error,
                                             {producer_down,
                                              {{crc32cer_nif_not_loaded,
                                                "/home/roger/IdeaProjects/redis/_build/default/lib/crc32cer/priv/crc32cer"},
                                               [{erlang,nif_error,
                                                 [{crc32cer_nif_not_loaded,
                                                   "/home/roger/IdeaProjects/redis/_build/default/lib/crc32cer/priv/crc32cer"}],
                                                 []},
                                                {crc32cer,nif,2,
                                                 [{file,
                                                   "/home/roger/IdeaProjects/redis/_build/default/lib/crc32cer/src/crc32cer.erl"},
                                                  {line,23}]},
                                                {kpro_batch,encode_tx,4,
                                                 [{file,
                                                   "/home/roger/IdeaProjects/redis/_build/default/lib/kafka_protocol/src/kpro_batch.erl"},
                                                  {line,97}]},
                                                {kpro_batch,encode,3,
                                                 [{file,
                                                   "/home/roger/IdeaProjects/redis/_build/default/lib/kafka_protocol/src/kpro_batch.erl"},
                                                  {line,47}]},
                                                {kpro_req_lib,produce,5,
                                                 [{file,
                                                   "/home/roger/IdeaProjects/redis/_build/default/lib/kafka_protocol/src/kpro_req_lib.erl"},
                                                  {line,206}]},
                                                {brod_producer,
                                                 '-init/1-fun-0-',8,
                                                 [{file,
                                                   "/home/roger/IdeaProjects/redis/_build/default/lib/brod/src/brod_producer.erl"},
                                                  {line,285}]},
                                                {brod_producer_buffer,
                                                 do_send,4,
                                                 [{file,
                                                   "/home/roger/IdeaProjects/redis/_build/default/lib/brod/src/brod_producer_buffer.erl"},
                                                  {line,273}]},
                                                {brod_producer,maybe_produce,
                                                 1,
                                                 [{file,
                                                   "/home/roger/IdeaProjects/redis/_build/default/lib/brod/src/brod_producer.erl"},
                                                  {line,498}]}]}}}
```

Driving me just a little nuts trying to find the problem, any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: The C code for the `crc32cer` library was not compiled correctly for some reason. One thing you could try is deleting the entire `_build` directory and recompiling everything.

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed the problem - note to self: in the future if these things happen delete the _build and recompile everything.